# C from char to name of function

Tags: c, file, struct

I want to read a file which has lots of names of library functions that are included in math.h like this:

```
sqrt
sin
cos
acos
asin
```

Using files I am going to get characters, but I want to put it into a structure that is a pointer to this function. The structure is like this:

```
typedef struct {
    char l[N];
    double value;
    int MOD;
    double (*function)(double);
} st ;
```

The pointer to the function is double (*function)(double)
How can I transform the character, that I'm going to read from the file, to a pointer to a function?

Comment: You need a structure (sorted preferably or hashed) from name to function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53277258/how-to-evaluate-calculate-expression-in-form-of-string-im-using-stm32f4?noredirect=1#comment93438550_53277258

Comment: What is the meaning of value and MOD fields?

Comment: `char l[N];` don't use names like `l`, but rather use meaningful names.

Comment: You need to read the chapter dealing with files and the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book.

Comment: Depends on your platform. E.g. on Linux you could use `dlsym`.

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of structs

```
struct Match {
    char name[20]; // enough
    double (*fx)(double);
};

struct Match m[] = { /* sorted for bsearch */
    {"acos", acos},
    {"asin", asin},
    {"cos", cos},
    {"sin", sin},
    // ...
    {"sqrt", sqrt},
};

// etc

struct Match *mm = bsearch("asin", m, sizeof m / sizeof *m, cmpnames));
if (mm) newvalue = mm->fx(oldvalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Don't forget include math header(math.h)

After you read function name from the file in the array of chars, use function `strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2)`, which return 0 if `str1 == str2 // character by character`. 
Then you can write code like this:

`double val;

if (strcmp(st->l, "sqrt") == 0)

{

stTemp->function = sqrt;

val = stTemp->function(value); // calculate sqrt(value)

} else if (strcmp(st->l, "sin"))

{

stTemp->function = sin;

val = stTemp->function(value); // calculate sin(value)

} //etc`

> Assuming that stTemp is the pointer to st struct